# Counting Spaces in input and getting a massive number of them

Tags: c

I'm going through the C Programming Language 2nd Edition and am stuck on Exercise 1-8.  I get the correct output for the number of newlines and the number of tabs, but I get an incorrect number of spaces.

```
# include <stdio.h>

main() {
    /* we use long as the int bit storage is rather limited */
    long blanks, tabs, newlines;
    /* c is an int as we are checking it against the ASCII values */
    int c;

    printf("Enter text: ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            blanks++;
        }
        if (c == '\t') {
            tabs++;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
           newlines++;
        }
    }
    printf("Spaces = %d\nTabs = %d\nNewlines = %d\n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
}
```

Using this as input (note that I am using `\t` and `\n` to show where I am pressing tab and return to make it obvious):

```
hello there c\t
\n
\n
\n
```

Gets me the output:

```
Spaces = 1408281626
Tabs = 1
Newlines = 3
```

Is there a reason I am getting such a massive number of spaces?  I have looked at other answers and my answer seems sound, I thought that maybe it might have something to do with the terminal I am using.  I am using a Macbook on El Capitan, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: You aren't initializing your variables

Comment: ...I feel so stupid... Thank you.

Comment: If you are coming from a language like Visual Basic which has default values for variables it is an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall` `-Werror` options.  If you had, the compiler would have flagged your problem.  To see, remove the initialization, add the options and recompile.  No matter how experienced one is, the warning options are always useful

Comment: @CraigEstey Thats an awesome tip that the book hasn't mentioned yet.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnColeman Another question, should I also initialize my `c` variable?  Using @CraigEstey tip to compile, it does not warn that I should initialize it, is there a reason?

Comment: The book [K&R--which I commend you for] probably won't mention it as it's not part of the language per se.  K&R was written before gcc/clang introduced the options

Comment: @Cagrosso no reason to initialize that variable since you assign a value to it prior to doing anything with it -- though it wouldn't hurt to initialize it.

Comment: @JohnColeman Understood, thanks.

Comment: Note that `' '` is a `space`.  `blank` usually refers to `' '` and `'\t'`.  See for example the `isblank(c)` function defined in `<ctype.h>`.  Confusingly enough, `isspace(c)` tests for all whitespace characters, including `' '`, `'\t'`, '`\n'` and a few others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- Always initialize your variables.
- Use correct format for `printf`. You are using `long` so `%ld` instead of `%d`.

So,

`long blanks = 0, tabs = 0, newlines = 0;`

and,

`printf("Spaces = %ld\nTabs = %ld\nNewlines = %ld\n", blanks, tabs, newlines);`

Comment: It is a wrong statement that variables always must be initialized.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think that's a good practice rather than a rule. Would appreciate if you can point me to a reference where local variable initialization is not needed or not recommended. Thanks.

Comment: @artm: It is definitely a rule that variables must be initialized before their values are used in a computation.  The compiler can help trying to avoid this kind of error if properly fitted with the appropriate warning level (eg: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`).  It is a shame that they don't at least issue warnings for this by default.

Comment: @chqrlie: yes I totally agree. Just a bit surprised by what Vlad said, which caused me to think that in some (exception) cases, it's not needed or recommended.

Comment: @artm: it is not needed if the variable is later set before use.  For example if you define `int i;` at the beginning of a function and use `i` as an index in a `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)` loop.  C99 allows to define `i` inside the `for` statement, but you might want pre-c99 portability.  In such a case, initializing `i` at definition time would make the casual reader wonder why `i` needs to be initialized before the `for` loop...

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialize the following variables

```
long blanks, tabs, newlines;
```

Write instead

```
long blanks = 0, tabs = 0, newlines = 0;
```

Also use format specifier `%ld` in this call of `printf`

```
printf("Spaces = %ld\nTabs = %ld\nNewlines = %ld\n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
```

Take into account that according to the C Stnadard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```